# Implications of multiple ways to order eight numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, permutations, combinations, linear-programming

Consider two sets $A,B$ composed of **four** real numbers each.

These eight real numbers are in $[0,1]$.

Consider other four real numbers $c,d,e,f$ each in $[0,1]$, **all different between each other**.

**Assume** there exists a way of ordering the four numbers in each set $A,B$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
w^A_1+w^B_1=c\\
w^A_2+w^B_2=d\\
w^A_3+w^B_3=e\\
w^A_4+w^B_4=f\\
\end{cases}
$$
where

- $w^A_h$ denotes the $h$th element of set $A$ once we have ordered its 4 elements
- $w^B_h$ denotes the $h$th element of set $B$ once we have ordered its 4 elements

**Claim:** if such an ordering is not unique, then it should be that two numbers in $A$ are equal and/or that two numbers in $B$ are equal.

Is this claim correct? If yes, how can I prove it? If not, can you provide a counterexample?

(similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3049673/implications-of-multiple-ways-to-order-four-numbers) but with 2 elements per set)

---

Maybe the claim is wrong? Let $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$ be the elements of $A$ and $\{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\}$ be the elements of $B$. We could have:

**order I**
$$
\begin{cases}
a_2+b_3=c\\
a_4+b_4=d\\
a_1+b_1=e\\
a_3+b_2=f
\end{cases}
$$

and

**order II**
$$
\begin{cases}
a_1+b_2=c\\
a_2+b_1=d\\
a_3+b_4=e\\
a_4+b_3=f
\end{cases}
$$

which implies
$$
\begin{cases}
a_2+b_3=a_1+b_2\\
a_4+b_4=a_2+b_1\\
a_1+b_1=a_3+b_4\\
a_3+b_2=a_4+b_3
\end{cases}
$$
Does this imply that two numbers in $A$ are equal and/or that two numbers in $B$ are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is wrong. Pick the following partial solution of the last system: $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(0,a,a’,a+a’)$ and  $(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)=(a’,a+b,b,0)$. Then $(c,d,e,f)=(a+b,a+a’,a’,a+a’+b)$. For instance, we can put $a=0.1$, $a’=0.15$ and $b=0.2$. Then $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(0,0.1,0.15,0.25)$, $(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)=(0.15,0.3,0.2,0)$, and $(c,d,e,f)=(0.3,0.25,0.15,0.45)$.